# Append data as table in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have an application what takes the date from inputs and saving it, the data are apendded bellow, something like todo list. But now i  have an issue trying to display the data, because i want to display it in a specific order as table row, but now the data is not showing properly, because i want to have Name under Name, Old under old, delete button under delete Text, ad edit button under edit text.

How to do this?

link to my application: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-moore-g86kd

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.

- You don't have any state to keep track of the added users
- On a form submit instead of updating the data you're trying to directly update the DOM with submitted data. Which is not the right way to do things in react.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    old: ""
  });
  // A new state to keep track of the added users
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const changeUser = e => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [e.target.name]: v
    });
  };

  // On form submit, all you need to do is to update the users state
  // Then render will take care of the rest
  const submitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUsers([...users, user]);
  };

  // This is how in react we update the content
  // Whenever, there is a change in state, this will get called and content will be updated
  // Ps: It's being called in the render
  const renderBody = () => {
    const content = [];

    users.map(item => {
      content.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.old}</td>
          <td>Delete btn</td>
          <td>Edit btn</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return content;
  };

  return (
    <div className="to-do">
      <form action="" onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <label htmlFor="">
          Name
          <input
            name="name"
            onChange={changeUser}
            value={user.name}
            type="text"
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="yes">
          Old Yes
          <input
            id="yes"
            name="old"
            onChange={changeUser}
            value="yes"
            type="radio"
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="no">
          Old No
          <input
            id="no"
            name="old"
            onChange={changeUser}
            value="no"
            type="radio"
          />
        </label>
        <input value={user.old} type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
      </form>
      <div className="res">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>OLD</th>
            <th>DELETE</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>
          <tr id="res" />

          {renderBody()}

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So what you need

- State for users to keep track of the added users
- On form submit, a trigger to update that users state
- A loop, to iterate over users array and return table rows with content

Comment: i want to add delete functionalitiy and edit functionality, but how can i manage to do this? I supose that i should use something like this:   `<td onClick={deleteUser}>Delete btn</td>
                    <td onClick={editUser}>Edit btn</td>`  But how to conect these functions with the state? and how to detect when i click on an delete button, that i should delete the corresponded item from state?

Comment: Yes, you would need separate functions to update the state on edit/delete. `const deleteUser = (index) => {let usersCopy = users; usersCopy.splice(index, 1);   setUsers(usersCopy);}`

Comment: i changed my code in the question, but it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? edit/delete or solution to your actual question?